# Check existence of improper parametric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals

Let be $\int\limits_1^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ln(t) ~dt$, where $x\in(1,\infty)$. We ca find an upper bound of the integrand by applying the series representation of $e^{-t}$ and the fact that $\ln(t)\leq t$ for $t\geq 1$:

$|t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ln(t)|\leq t^{x-1}e^{-t}t = t^xe^{-t}\leq t^x \frac{\lceil 2x\rceil !}{t^{\lceil 2x\rceil}}\leq \frac{\lceil 2x\rceil !}{t^x}$.

So we can write:

$\int\limits_1^{\infty}|t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ln(t) ~dt|\leq \lceil 2x\rceil ! \int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^x}dt= \lceil 2x\rceil ! \left(\frac{1}{1-x}t^{1-x}\right)\bigg \vert_1^{\infty}= -\frac{\lceil 2x\rceil !}{1-x}$.

So the parametric integral exists.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know about the inequality $t^xe^{-t}\le \frac{\lceil 2x\rceil !}{t^x}$, but in the last equation it has to be $\frac{\lceil 2x\rceil !}{x-1}$. Besides from that, it looks fine.

Comment: I added the missing "$-$", thanks